# PHP 2D Array Calculations

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get this PHP script to calculate the sum of numbers in the box, but I want to ignore the first row and first col in the calculation; yet keep them in the grid.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    $n = 3;

    for($i=0; $i<=$n; $i++) { // rows
        for($j=0; $j<=$n; $j++) { // columns
            $value[$i][$j] = rand(1,20);
        }
    }

    print "<table>";    
        for($j=0; $j<$n; $j++)  { // Runs the loop times $n
            print "<tr>";
                for($k=0; $k<$n; $k++)  { // Runs the loop times $n
                    print "<td>" . $value[$j][$k] . "</td>";
                }   
        print   "</tr>";    
        }   
    print   "</table>";


    $space = '';
    $sum = 0;

    for ($a = 0; $a < $n; $a++) {
        for($b = 0; $b < $n; $b++) {  
            $sum += $value[$a][$b];
            if ($a == ($n - 1) && $b == ($n - 1)) {
                $space .= $value[$a][$b];
            } else {
                $space .= $value[$a][$b].' + ';
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<br>" . $space.' = '.$sum;

?>
```

Comment: what is input? what is output? And what output you expected?show us so that we can help you

Comment: So you don't want to sum anything from `$value[0]` or any `$value[$i][0]`?

Comment: first row and first col...would be the top left value?, so you only want to skip one value?

Comment: It could be as simple as changing `$a = 0` / `$b = 0` to `$a = 1` / `$b = 1` in `for ($a = 0; $a < $n; $a++) {  for($b = 0; $b < $n; $b++) { ...` => `for ($a = 1; $a < $n; $a++) {  for($b = 1; $b < $n; $b++) { ...`, so it skips the 1st row and the 1st column.

Comment: @Andrew we would like to skip the whole first column and first row

Comment: @A-2-A Our input is $n.

So if $n = 3 then we would have an output like:

**3 6 5<br>
12 18 1<br>
3 16 8<br><br>
3 + 6 + 5 + 12 + 18 + 1 + 3 + 16 + 8 = 72**

However we want the sum to not include the first column or first row so our output should be:

**3 6 5<br>
12 18 1<br>
3 16 8<br><br>
18 + 1 + 3 + 16 + 8 = 30**

Thanks

Comment: @DavidMartin then as Sean mentioned, change it to `$a = 1` and `$b = 1` in your `for` loop statement

Comment: in your example in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724154/php-2d-array-calculations#comment55218087_33724154) you don't want row 1 or column 1 of row 2, but  do want column 1 of row 3? correct?

Comment: @Sean + Andrew we tried that and it worked perfectly, thanks very much for your help everyone